# how show text of editText in dialogFragment on MainActivity in xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, dialogfragment

I am using dialogfragment to make login Page in Xamarin Android.
I want to click on the login button (Photo below) ,Display text of User Name in the dialog on MainActivity after dismiss.
help me please!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDB3W.jpg)

loginDialog class:

```
class loginDialog:DialogFragment
{

    EditText txtUser;
    Button btnLogin;
    private Context context;
    public loginDialog(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_layer, container, false);
        txtUser = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUser);
        btnLogin = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.Click += BtnLogin_Click;

        return view;
    }
    private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dismiss();
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView userName;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        userName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblUserName);

        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        loginDialog ld = new loginDialog(this);
        ld.Show(ft, "");
    }


    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call  the findViewById on your dialog like:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(Resource.id.project_name);
if (editText != null) {
    Log.e("", "Value is: " + editText.getText());
} else {
    Log.e("", "EditText not found!");
}
```